# Running 2 civicrm instances on 1 database

Tags: database, installation

I have one mySQL database and one Apache webserver. Can I still run 2 separate wordpress/Civicrm environments (like staging and production)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have multiple Civi/CMS instances on the same server. Depending on your preference, when looking at your server, you will see something along the lines of one of the the following structure:

[image]

Per comment - editing my response to include database - unless you are setting up a multi-site instance of Civi, you would need a separate database for each CMS instance.

Comment: did you answer the issue that they only have one db?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your explanation, but as mentioned in the previous comment, it does not solve my issue. I have only one database. If there a possibility to work with different table prefixes? For instance civicrm_contact is used for production, staging_civicrm_contact is used for staging?

Comment: You might be able to add tables to the Civi database without breaking it, but you would have no way of telling Civi to store something in the staging_ table vs. the civicrm_ table. You can change the mode of your database from production to demo/staging, but that doesn't create a whole new set of tables in the database, it simply prevents emails being sent out and cron jobs will not be executed. Admittedly, I'm not technical, but it is unclear to me (unless you are unable to add server resources) why you are limited to a single database?